# Reading Json file from github pages server using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, github-pages

I am building my website on github pages which can only host a static website. However it does allow use of javascript. So I have a json file on the github server from where my website runs and I want to fetch and process it using javascript. The link to the file is below

https://bioinfobot.github.io/data/2017-05.json

more specifically it is located at data/2017-05.json

If you click on the link above it will show the attributes of my json file.

I tried many tweaks from stack exchange but nothing is working out for me. Can someone please give me a simple code to just to invoke this file to an object. I can do the rest from there on. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this using jquery

```
 $.getJSON("https://bioinfobot.github.io/data/2017-05.json")
    .done(function( data ) {
       console.log(data)
    });
```

**OR**

```
$.getJSON("https://bioinfobot.github.io/data/2017-05.json", function(json) {
    console.log(json); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just make a request:

```js
fetch('https://bioinfobot.github.io/data/2017-05.json')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => {
    //json vaiable contains object with data
  })
```

Comment: this works, thanks. But I think now Github requests a token query to be able to read files.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
   $.getJSON("https://bioinfobot.github.io/data/2017-05.json",function(data)
   {console.log(data)});
})();
```